# Android App UI keeps changing, causing the UI Automation based scripts be changed frequently

Tags: android, user-interface, automation

I write in order to know your experience on the android automation.
We have some Apps in developing. And we QA team write a lot of android ui automation script in order to test the app automatically. 
But we have the problem that the UI of the Apps changes for each public release.

That's the problem. UI keeps changing, and our script developing team needs to keep changing the script...

Do you guys have the same problems??? Could you please share me some good practice on this? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which tools you are using for your automation, but in general they all (as far as I know) give you multiple ways of locating the elements you want to interact with.  Some ways of locating the elements are more fragile than others.  As an example, compare using xpath locators vs id's.  The xpath of an element is likely to change any time that a layout change is made to the UI.  But an id will always work if it is unique (as it should be).

However, any time a workflow changes on a UI the existing tests on that screen will likely need updating.  This is unavoidable, and is best remedied by your automation engineers working in tandem with the developer for that work.  By the time the feature is done, the automation suite should have been updated to handle the changes.

People resorting to using things like xpath locators, is usually due to less fragile locators not being available.  This is especially true when creating an automation suite for an existing/legacy product.  In this case it would probably be a good idea to look into getting things like id's added to your UI elements.  It would take up some development time which is often at a premium, but in most cases it would pay off in the long term when you don't have to spend as long fixing tests.  Also, having an automation suite you can't rely on negates a lot of the benefits of having one in the first place.  When people can't trust the tests they will start checking things manually to make sure that nothing is broken, taking up time that could be better used elsewhere.